# JS onscrollStop event become more and more slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I use the fllowing code to perform as a `onscrollStop` event:

```
let timeoutId = null;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if(timeoutId)clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("ok!");
    }, 200);
});
```

The problem is, when I test this on Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit), the "ok!" log turns to be more and more slow(try to scroll more times, at least 30 times).

i.e. sometimes it shows immediately when scroll is end(200ms), but sometimes it shows long time after the scroll is end(max to 1s).

Then I test it on Microsoft Edge, IE and Firefox , it runs perfectly.

Another thing I noticed is that, such codes needs plenty of CPUs, when I test in Microsoft Edge, IE and Firefox, my CPU runs max to 40%. But chrome won't.(if you can't reproduce this, try to replace the log function with a more complicated function.)

So I believe it is chrome's safety strategy of CPU that prevent the code to run as fast as expected.

So obviously, the problem is the code is too unefficient.

Is there a more efficient way to implement a `scrollstop` event?

Comment: That code works fine for me, 58.0.3029.110 x64. It's probably some other script on the page causing this. The way you've done it there is pretty standard.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but don't use `let` unless you're compiling it to ES5, as it's a ES6 feature and is only supported on modern browsers.

Comment: Open the inspector, and click on the `html` element in the DOM tree. Then click on the "Event Listeners" tab, next to the "Styles" tab, and check the "Ancestors" box, and see if there is more than one scroll event listed there.

Comment: @thephpdev Yes, you are right, I separate this code from my project, and it runs well. But the event listenner only shows one jquery handler, how can I find all the handler that is register using jquery?(the project is too large for me to dig into.)

Comment: There's no easy way to do that, but you could replace jQuery with the development, unminified version, and then check the "Event Listeners" tab again to fine the exact line of code that sets the event listener, and then you can add `throw new Error('event set')` just above that line, then you'll get a debug backtrace in the console, showing you the call chain.

Comment: @thephpdev Thanks a lot, I successfully list all handlers.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help